# How to find a string contains specific character and replace it with a HTML tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to find all words that starts `@` the character in a string and change it to the `<a>` HTML tag.

For example:

```
my_string = 'Hello @username this is your page'
# in my_string i want replace @username like:
@username => <a href='mysite.com/username'>@username</a>
# expected output => 
Hello <a href='mysite.com/username' >@username</a> this is your page
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Any reason that `Hello <%= link_to @username, "mysite.com/#{@username}" %> this is your page` is not a viable option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`String#gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regex:

```
my_string = 'Hello @username this is your page'
my_string.gsub(/@(\w+)/,'<a href=\'mysite.com/\1\'>@\1</a>' )
#=> "Hello <a href='mysite.com/username'>@username</a> this is your page"
```

Regex explanation:

- `@\w+` in regex means `@` and one or more word characters (`\w` stands for alphanumerical characters or an underscore)
- `(...)` in regex catches the username in a capturing group, that can be used later in replacements
- `\1` in a second `gsub` argument instructs `gsub` to put contents of the first capturing group to this place of the string - in this case, the username

Comment: While `gsub` would still be my recommendation I have to assume the OP was looking for `my_string.gsub(/(@\w+)/,"@username" => "<a href=\'mysite.com/#{@username}\'>#{@username}</a>")` so as to substitute in the instance variable

Comment: Note that this solution is vulnerable to XSS, so make sure to either properly escape the username or don't render this string as HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of mrazza is doing very well the job. But if you want to avoid using regex I guess it could be helpful.

```rb
result = []
splitted_string = 'Hello @username this is your page'.split

splitted_string.each_with_index do |a, i|
  result << a
  if a.include? '@'
    result.insert(i, "<a href='mysite.com/username' >", a, "</a>")
          .delete_at(i + 3)
  end
end
p result.join(' ')
#=> "Hello <a href='mysite.com/username'>@username</a> this is your page"
```

Basically you split your string to get an array, you iterate over it and if you find an `@` you add the element you want between it by using index.

If you don't want to delete an element which can be tricky, you can write the following line between your statement:

```
result.insert(i, "<a href='mysite.com/username' >")
result.insert(i + 2, "</a>")
```